# Gradle-jooq-plugin task generateJooq only generates information_schema classes from my H2 DBMS , but not my created ones with Liquibase

Tags: java, gradle, h2, jooq, jooq-codegen

I am creating Spring Boot project and using Liquibase, JOOQ , Gradle, Java 17 and H2 DBMS. I want to generate classes from my database and I am using gradle-jooq-plugin for that. Every time I try to to use task :generateJooq I get information_schema generated instead of my classes from Liquibase:

[image: generated classes image]

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "8.0"
}

buildscript {
    configurations["classpath"].resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.jooq") {
            useVersion("3.16.3")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        
    }


}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    jooqGenerator("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    implementation("org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.28")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta-extensions-liquibase")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.30")

    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.3")

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


jooq {
    version.set("3.16.3")
    edition.set(nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS)

    configurations {
        create("main") {
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(true)

            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                jdbc.apply {
                    driver = "org.h2.Driver"
                    url = "jdbc:h2:~/jooqtest"
                    user = "db"
                    password = "db"
                }

                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.h2.H2Database"
                        forcedTypes.addAll(listOf(
                                org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType().apply {
                                    name = "varchar"
                                    includeExpression = ".*"
                                    includeTypes = "JSONB?"
                                },
                                org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType().apply {
                                    name = "varchar"
                                    includeExpression = ".*"
                                    includeTypes = "INET"
                                }
                        ))
                    }

                    generate.apply {
                        isDeprecated = false
                        isRecords = true
                        isImmutablePojos = true
                        isFluentSetters = true
                    }
                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "com.example.main.db"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my application.properties file looks like this:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.username=db
spring.datasource.password=db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:jooqtest
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

I would be very thankful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [jOOQ code generation manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/) and also throughout the [third party plugin documentation](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin), you have to specify an `inputSchema` if you don't want the code generator to generate *all* schemas.

Specifically:

```
database.apply {
    name = "org.jooq.meta.h2.H2Database"
    inputSchema = "PUBLIC"
    ...
}
```